# What does pk__in mean in Django?

Tags: python, django

```
Model.objects.filter(pk__in=[list of ids])
```

and

```
Model.objects.filter(pk__in=[1,2,3])
```

How do I show this data in a template?

```
def xx(request):
    return HttpResponse(Model.objects.filter(pk__in=[1,2,3]))
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It means, give me all objects of model `Model` that either have `1`,`2` or `3` as their primary key.

See [Field lookups - in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#in).

You get a list of objects back you can show them in the template like every other list, using the [`for` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for):

```
{% for object in objects %}
    Some value: {{ object.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

To learn how to create a Django application you should read the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/#intro-tutorial01) or the [Django book](https://www.djangobook.com/en/3.2/).

Comment: All links have rotted.

Answer (score 0):

A tricky way to batch select (a best practice when dealing with a lot of data).
it would be faster than calling get/get_or_create in a loop due to the fact that only one SQL query is sent.

Try to time this :

```
Model.objects.filter(pk__in=[list of ids])
```

and this :

```
[Model.objects.get(pk=i) for i in ids]
```

Also note that running on your laptop there is minimal latency when django communicates with the database (production might be different).